# Cannot read property of null - Property not loaded fast enough for Binding?

Tags: angular, firebase

in the Chatroom Window, my App greets the user with his currentUser.name from the auth service.
It works as expected, but throws 5 repeated Errors at the same time:

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null"

I have no idea why the app would throw this many, but I know the reason is, that the property hasn't loaded quickly enough before the DOM is rendered.

How do I make the DOM wait for the binding to have loaded?

The .ts file:

```
  constructor(private auth: AuthService)
  {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
      this.currentUser = user;
    });
  }
```

the html:

```
  <div class="select-room-message">
    Choose a Chat, {{this.currentUser.name}}
  </div>
```

My Auth Service:

```
  public currentUser: Observable <User | null>;


  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    this.currentUser = this.afAuth.authState
    .pipe(switchMap((user) => {
      console.log('user ' + user);
     if (user) {
       return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
     } else {
       return of(null);
     }
   }));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your HTML as:

```
<div class="select-room-message">
    Choose a Chat, {{currentUser?.name}}
</div>
```

This `?` is called safe navigation operator, this will not try to read the property `name` until `currentUser` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Since currentUser is an Observable, you need to use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to react to changes to it. If it's able to be null/undefined, you'll need the safe nav operator that [xyz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149389/10747134) points out.

```
<div class="select-room-message">
    Choose a Chat, {{(currentUser | async)?.name}}
</div>
```